# Arrange a tibble based on 2 columns in R?

Tags: r

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66303244/r-tibble-arrange-by-two-columns)... however, I cant get it to work in my case and Im not sure why.

I am trying to arrange a tibble based on 2 columns. For example, in my data, I am trying to arrange by the `value` and `count` columns. To begin, I show a working example:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- tibble(
  value = c("B", "D", "D", "E", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "E"),
  ids = c(1:10),
  count = c(3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1)
)

 dat %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(valrank = min(ids)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(valrank, value, desc(count))
```

looking at the output:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   value   ids count valrank
   <chr> <int> <dbl>   <int>
 1 B         1     3       1
 2 B         7     2       1
 3 B         9     1       1
 4 D         2     2       2
 5 D         3     1       2
 6 E         4     2       4
 7 E        10     1       4
 8 A         5     2       5
 9 A         6     1       5
10 C         8     1       8
```

We can see that the code worked... the tibble is arranged by the `value` column, and the order is based on how many times each element appears in the tibble (ie, the `count`).

However, when I try the following example, the same code doesn't work:

```
dat_1 <- tibble(
   value = c("x2....", "x5...." , "x5....", "x3...." , "x3....", "x4....", "x3....", "x3....", "x4....", "x2...." ),
   ids = c(1:10),
   count = c(2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
 )

 dat_1 %>%
   group_by(value) %>%
   mutate(valrank = min(ids)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   arrange(valrank, value, desc(count))
```

Looking at this output, we get:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   value    ids count valrank
   <chr>  <int> <dbl>   <int>
 1 x2....     1     2       1
 2 x2....    10     1       1
 3 x5....     2     2       2
 4 x5....     3     1       2
 5 x3....     4     4       4
 6 x3....     5     3       4
 7 x3....     7     2       4
 8 x3....     8     1       4
 9 x4....     6     2       6
10 x4....     9     1       6
```

So we can see, this has failed to reorder the tibble based on the `count`. In the 2nd example, `x3` appears the most (i.e., has the highest count), so should appear at the top of the tibble.

I'm not sure what Im doing wrong here!?

**UPDATE:**

I think I may have solved this problem with:

```
dat_1  %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(valrank = max(count)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(-valrank, value, -count)
```

Comment: You `arrange` by `valrank` at the first position. What is specific condition of order you want?

Comment: Essentially, I want to group together identical `value` entries. Then I want to order these groups by how many entires each group contains. So, in my 2nd example, `x3` appears 4 times, so the group of `x3`s would be top of my tibble. After that `x2`, `x4`, and `x5` all appear twice, so their respective groups would come next in my tibble.

Comment: Opting to vote close as a typo equivalent. I suppose you could cal it a thinkoe. The code did what you told it to.

Comment: I was pretty hesitating because of `min(ids)` but `max(count)` make this problem clear and now solved..

Comment: Please post your update as an answer to your question, it's good so people won't spent time to read your question as well as they may learn from your experience.

Comment: The ordering of the sorting (arrange) is explicit in your call of `arrange()`. Per your comment, you want to first order by `value`, then by descending `count`, so your call should be `arrange(value, -count)`. Your comment does not mention `valrank`, so I have omitted it here.